# Import CSS styles from HTML snippet

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-parsing

I'm playing around with dynamically loaded HTML content on a webpage I am building. What I want is to have a list of HTML files with snippets that will be dynamically imported into my webpage using javascript/jquery and an ajax request. This would allow me to e.g. store several blog posts as separate files and dynamically build a page with multiple posts on it.

Below is an example snippet with just a title and a small table:

CSS :

```
#swimTimes2{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

HTML SOURCE :

```
<div id="itemContainer">
    <div id='swimTimes2' class='item'>
        <h1> Swim Times </h1>
        <table>
            <tr class="tableHead">
                <td>Weekdays</td><td>Weekends</td><td>Holidays</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7:00am-9:00am</td><td>10:30am-8:00pm</td><td>11:00am-4:00pm</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00am-2:00pm</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4:00pm-10:30pm</td></tr>

        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

I figured out that by using `$.get()` I can load the contents of my snippet file above and then use jquery to search through it for the html snippet I want, in this case the contents of #itemContainer.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    loadContent('content/content_1.html');
});


function loadContent(fileName){

    $.get(fileName, function(data){

        var htmlContents = $(data).find("#itemContainer").children('.item').html();
        var id = $(data).find("#itemContainer").children('.item').attr('id');
        $('#content').append($('<div class="item" />').attr('id', id).html(htmlContents));

        var styleEl = $(data).find("style");
        $('head').append(styleEl);

    });
}
```

So the first 3 lines of my `$.get()` handler function work - I am able to import the snippet and put it up on my html page. Now I want to import also the css styles from the snippet into my main page - in this example I gave my item a grey background, a property that it wouldn't get from my main html page.

The issue I have is that although I know the style element from my snippet is being imported into my main page, the css rules it contains are not applied to the imported html. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know that your imported styles are in the right place?  Do they show up when you inspect the page code?

Comment: Is the imported page in an `ifram`? Otherwise, you might have issues having two `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Comment: @Ghillied I am not using an i-frame. I'm taking the contents of `#itemContainer` as a string and interpreting it as a jquery element, then appending it to a div on my main page.

Comment: @MarcAudet as you said, I know they show up by using 'Inspect Element(Q)' in Firefox - it appears as second `<style>` item in the head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a similar thing to the second example on the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
var styleProps = $(this).css( ["width", "height", "color", "background-color"] );
$.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
  html.push( prop + ": " + value );
});

$( "#result" ).html( html.join( "<br>" ) );
```

The only negative thing is that you have to list in the `.css` which attributes you want. However if you put all of the possible attributes it likely still work because there is nothing is truly `null` unless the value is specified to be `''`

Comment: I'm assuming you would also have to do this for each element in the snippet, right?

Comment: You could use a loop to iterate through them all, but I believe so

Comment: Ok, I tried this but I don't think it works because the html is not actually being rendered by a browser, just explored using Jquery, so the CSS is not going to be interpreted. a command like `$('#swimTimes2').css(["background"]);` returns `({'background-color':"transparent"})`, meaning that the background-color statement is never applied to the html element.

This makes me think, though, that it would be possible to parse the css rules by selector and apply them individually.

Comment: Yes, but you can change the css of an object using `.css` as well using the format `$("#swimTimes2").css({'background' : 'grey', 'height': '50px'});`. This means you can create an array in the `.each` loop to store each css attribute (using identifiers like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/YW2QG/2/)) and put it onto another element using the `.css` format `$("#swimTimes2").css({'background' : array["background"], 'height': array["height"]});`